# How to hide columns using vue-tables-2 - Vuejs -

Tags: vue.js, vue-tables-2

I've really exhausted all the possible results in google but still can't find the answer. If there is one.
I need to do one simple thing: Using  Vuejs and Vue-tables-2 (https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-tables-2), I need to hide one column, depending on if the user is admin or not, of course, before the table is loaded.

I've tried different approaches but without success. I think that the closest one is using computed propierties, but withou success.

I will not copy code since it is really unnecesary, all I've done didn't work and I am at the beginning again.

I really appreciate if someone could help me.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation page it looks like you control what columns are present in the table through an array:

```
 data: {
        columns: ['id', 'name', 'age'],
        tableData: [
            { id: 1, name: "John", age: "20" },
            { id: 2, name: "Jane", age: "24" },
            { id: 3, name: "Susan", age: "16" },
            { id: 4, name: "Chris", age: "55" },
            { id: 5, name: "Dan", age: "40" }
        ]
    };
```

Therefore when the page is loaded, you modify the array `columns` to add or remove columns from your table dependant on the user type.